# Exit the method after call but method should continue processing submitted request in JAVA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, process, runtime, threadpool

**Problem Statement -**
I have developed a web application which creates set of task based on user input and execute those task on remote 
server (linux) in sequentail order one by one. Each task takes around 10 minutes of complete. Normally user submit 5 task in one request which means web application takes around 50 minute to show success /failure message on user screen after 
task submission. **I do not want the user to keep waiting for 50 minute in order to show output result , instead I want to render on message page and expecting the method should continue processing on passed data .**

**Current Implementation -**
Controller will get all required data to prepare task from user and pass to service class which will create task list - List and start
executing them as below by calling executeTask method. Once the complete task get executed  then only I can show final Success /Failure message to user as of now. But I 
want to exit after calling  executeTask() by passing taskList and expecting below Outcome -

1) executeTask() method should continue processing submitted data even after exit from method.

2) I will render user to Success Page with message - Your request has been submitted successfully. You will get notification message after task execution completion.

```
public List<String> executeTask(List<Task> taskList){
        List<String> executionStatusList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Process process = null;

        for( Task task : taskList) {

          try {

                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(task );

                    if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
                        int exitVal = process.exitValue();
                        executionStatusList.add("SUCCESS");

                } else {
                        executionStatusList.add("ERROR");
                break; //Since error occured while processing the task , exiting without processing other task with error status.
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioException) {
                //LOGS
                } catch (InterruptedException intrruptdExcptn) {
                //LOGS
                } finally {
                    if (null != process) {
                        process.destroy();
                        executionStatusList.add("SUCCESS");
                    } else {
                        executionStatusList.add("ERROR");
                       break; //Since error occured while processing the task , exiting without processing other task with error status.
                    }

                }



        }
        return executionStatusList;
    }
```

Comment: Your code structure is not looks good. I can not get where is opening tag and where is closing tag.

Comment: Now Updated. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used spring supported Asynchronous feature to achieve given requirement. We need to add Asynchronous feature over the method which takes time to process. By doing so , that particular method will keep running on background and we can populate Submit message to user.

**Code Sample**

```
  @EnableAsync
    public class ServiceClassName {

    /**
    *Method which takes long time to process request. Here Need to add @Asyncn
    */
    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public void methodName ( DataaType inputParam) {

    //Your business logic goes here

    //If you want to return something, then do link  as below-
    //return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(returnValue);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a new thread which runs asynchronously and send back a 200 ok response to client? Use this to say that the request is noted and you will get a mail via email. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please explain more on this. Any good example or reference  ? Exactly what should I google to get good reference.

Comment: this is more of a subjective answer. You need to fork the work by creating a new thread and ending the main process. try some examples around multi threading you might get few references

Comment: Thanks for your input Bhargav. Your input helped me to know the area needs to be explored for solution. I am exploring Spring asynchronous request processing.